# Importing data into SQL from excel using ASP.NET by skipping n rows

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I am using following code to export data from excel into SQL using ASP.NET.

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Upload and save the file
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
    }
    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

        //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] 
        { 
            new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(DateTime)),
            new DataColumn("Designation",typeof(DateTime))});

        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
        }
        excel_con.Close();

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {

                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Employee";

                //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Designation", "Designation");

                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in my Excel file the actual data is starting from Row 7.
So it is not working but whenever i move data to row 1 it fetches and uploades the data in SQL just fine.
So what i want is to predefine in my code that pick the data from row 7 in excel file.
Also another query that my header name of SQL and Excel sheets are different, so unless both headers are same it does not pick the data, so is there anyway that i can keep the header different and still fetch the data?
Please help, as i am really stuck here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713048/skip-first-row-in-read-of-excel-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let excel know where to get the data from in your query try something like the following.

Change this row:

```
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
```

to this:

```
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "$" + "A7:ZZ]", excel_con))
```

Alter the cell & row parameters to meet your requirements...

Hope this helps.