# How To skip 15 rows in excel (take out the header)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, database

I Want to skip a few rows in an excel file, 15 rows(A1 to A14) to be able to import in sql server... But What I'm finding in internet doesn't work with me, I was thinking if you guys could take a look in my code

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    String strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HRD=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", excelConnection);

    excelConnection.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$] ", strConnection);

    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
    {
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Dados";
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Mov", "Data Mov.");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Valor", "Data Valor");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Descrição do Movimento", "Descrição do Movimento");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Valor em EUR", "Valor em EUR");

        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    }

    excelConnection.Close();
}
```

I already tried put the "IEnumerable" but it didn't work, I probably did it wrong.

Comment: What is the criteria by which you want to skip these certain rows? Are they in a certain position in the worksheet, or do they have certain values in a particular cell(s)? The nature of the criteria can help to determine how you achieve your goal. Please edit the question to include more detail.

Comment: @ADyson I want to skip 15 rows in excel to be able to import in database

Comment: yes...you already said that.  Read my comment again and then answer the more specific question contained in it. Thanks.

Comment: To simplify it: I asked _which_ 15 rows you want to skip.

Comment: @ADyson I don't know what you mean, what I want to do is skip the "header"... Normally the excel file start at A1 but I want to skip to A15 , or else my program doesnt work, gives me an error, because my columns just start at A15 and not A1

Comment: Right so you simply want to skip the first 15 rows? I thought maybe you wanted to skip, say 15 specific rows which all have one column empty or something. It wasn't clear.

Comment: Before the table on excel file, I have text, I want to skip to the part that the table starts not by editing the client file and by programing

Comment: @ADyson YEs thanks! Now what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: will it always be exactly 15 rows every time you run this code? Or can a different copy of the spreadsheet have a different number of rows you want to avoid?

Comment: P.S. if you want to "start at A15" as you said in your above comment, this implies skipping the first **14** rows, not 15. Is that correct? This contradicts what you have written in the question. Please clarify the correct row to start the import from.

Comment: Right now, I'm just doing this program with the same table, but probably later (I'm in training) My program will have to be able to do skips different numbers of rows

Comment: @ADyson Yeah my bad, I fix it the question

Comment: Ok. Well I have written an answer based on what is now in the question, exactly 14 rows being skipped. If it might vary, then you need some extra criteria by which to decide what to skip. Either you have to tell C# the exact number of rows to skip at the same time as you tell it which file to import, or you have to have some way of determining that from the content of the Excel file...e.g. knowing that certain cells will be blank in non-import rows, or similar. You'll have to think about what approach is going to suit the exact nature of the data you'll be processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you always want to skip exactly the first 14 rows and start your query importing at A15, then you can write your SQL query like this:

```
Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$A15:G]
```

Replace G with the correct column Letter

P.S. Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11694089/5947043) for this inspiration.

Comment: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'rptListaMovs_4$'A16:end''. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'rptListaMovs_4$'A16:end'' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.' Error

Comment: which line is throwing that error? I notice in your code that you try to run the SELECT query twice, the second of which (the line `SqlDataAdapter da = ...`) is using the wrong database connection to do so, and creates a dataAdapter which is never used. I'm not sure but I think you can remove that line. `DataSet ds = new DataSet();` appears to be unnecessary as well.

Comment: It's the First select that its giving me an error... I already took out the second select but nothing happened

Comment: There are some funny single quotes in that error message. To be clear, does your code look exactly like this: `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$A15:end]", excelConnection);` ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried put single quotes but without them gives me the same error

Comment: P.S. you also have an error in your connection string. `HRD=YES` is a) a typo (should be HDR) and b) not useful in this scenario because it only removes 1 row, not 15. You should remove this in case it is creating any issues.

Comment: Already took, It seems, that the program is thinking that is the name of the sheet

Comment: strange because every link I can find about this topic online suggests that this is the correct syntax to use. I can only thing maybe the "end" part could be a problem. Just replace with `Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$A15:ZZ]` and see if it helps or not

Comment: Didn't work bro, I try a lot of things, this was my last resource(stackoverflow)...

Comment: In that case I'd suggest to maybe use the approach in this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313273/5947043 . Load your data into a DataTable (using OleDbAdapter like in the code of the original question on that page) and then use Linq to skip the rows you don't want.

Comment: At this stage, there are a lot of things you say are now different from the code you initially wrote.

Comment: @MacroMarc are you talking to me or Pedro? And what is your point precisely? We have been trying to solve the problem, which might account for different attempts and versions. Have you got a suggestion?

Comment: I meant Pedro. I suggest Pedro edit his post, strip out the unnecessary stuff, and concentrate on the excel connection to read as a test. Clean up the quote situation, and make: `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$A15:G]", excelConnection);` Replace G with the correct column Letter

Comment: @MacroMarc if you want to address someone then put an @ followed by their username as I've done here. That way 1) it's clear to everyone who you means and 2) the intended recipient gets a notification. P.s. I don't see much different between your suggestion and mine...what do you think will help, from what you've written?

Comment: ZZ is above IU, which is 255 columns. So actually if you don't know the column, then put IU instead of G

Answer (score 1):

@MacroMarc and ADyson Helped me
Here's the solution:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$A15:D75]", excelConnection);
```

Insted of This:

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", excelConnection);
```